# How can I query these 4 tables by joining them?

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone help me and teach me to query this. Please..

Pawner table

[image: Pawner table]

Item table

[image: Item table]

loan_assignment table

[image: Loan table]

Loan table

[image: loan_assignment table]

When I join those 4 tables the result should be like this 
[image: report]
I had queried this but the result is redundant.

This is my query:

```
SELECT a.date_loan_granted, p.pawner_id, p.name, c.item_name, l.principal_loan
FROM loan_assignment a
JOIN pawner p ON p.pawner_id = a.pawner_id
JOIN item c ON c.item_id = a.item_id
JOIN loan l ON l.loan_id = a.loan_id;
```

The result of this query above ^ is this

[image]

Comment: try adding DISTINCT in your statement

Comment: Why are all the ID's 1? IDs being the identifier should be incremented, this could be the reason for this weird result which looks more like cross join.

Comment: @vkp http://imgur.com/moaGPhA still it produces the same thing. The row should produce 10-Jul-2015 | 1 | Mr. Michael Panganiban| Laptop | P500| Pawned and 10-Aug-2015 | 1 | Mr. Michael Panganiban| Laptop | P300| Pawned

Comment: @Nimesh It's the history log. I have use composite primary key so that I can trace transaction made by that person, Michael Panganiban

Comment: the columns you are joining on have more than one entry in the corresponding tables. Hence, the rows you are retrieving are not duplicates. You can check that by selecting other columns. If you really need DISTINCT rows, add conditions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Bring in this comment from my answer ... i am pretty sure the Loan table and Loan Assignment tables are mixed up in the pictures

Comment: *Note if your wondering why this is hard it is because you do not have a primary key on any of these tables, or foreign keys. In Item table, Item_ID should be unique, In Loan table loan_ID should be unique, In Loan_assignment Loan_ID/Pawner_ID should be unique, In Pawner Pawner ID should be unique

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue: In loan_assignment set the loan_id for 500 to 1 and 300 to 2. then on loan the value that is null for payment set the loan_id to 1 and the one with 200 set the loan_id to 2. should clear up your issue once you use distinct.

Your parent child relationship for these tables goes as follows

**Pawner**

```
PK: Pawner_ID 
FK: Pawnshop_ID
```

**Loan_assignment**

```
PK: None 
FK: Pawnshop_ID, Pawner_ID, Item_ID, Loan_ID
```

**Item**

```
PK: Item_ID
```

**Loan**

```
PK: Loan_ID
```

Right now structure should be:

```
A Pawn Shop can have multiple pawners.
A Pawner can have multiple loans. 
A Loan can have one or many items. 
An Item can have multiple payments.
```

here are some suggestions to fix your tables since using a distinct is not good enough to resolve your structure issue.

**Loan Assignment:** all loans belong to a pawnshop and a pawner (why not just have them belong to a pawner and remove the pawnshop since that information is redundant and can be found from the parent child relationship). This table needs its own primary key because each loan is treated different. This table should have the inital loan in it with the amount all the rest of the transactions that your trying to do here should be moved to a payment table with a PK of its own and a FK back to the loan it belongs to.

**Item Table:** The Item_ID field is the primary key for this table. the values need to be unique because each item is a piece of inventory you need to treat separate. you may want a FK in this table linking it back to the Loan Assignment so that a loan can have multiple items assigned to it.

**Loan:** this table needs to have some information moved to the loan table and some moved to the suggested payment table.

The table structure is not solid for what you would like to do. i recommend at this point going online and looking at the parent child relationship for a loan or pawn shop database that exists and working from that.

Comment: @loxp still it returns 4 rows even I used distinct

Comment: Yup i have a bug, its because of the two dollar amounts. i have updated my response.

Comment: @loxp so you are telling me that the loan_id in loan-assignment needs to be different to each other right?

Comment: In loan_assignment  set the loan_id for 500 to 1 and 300 to 2. then on loan the value that is null for payment set the loan_id to 1 and the one with 200 set the loan_id to 2. should clear up your issue once you use distinct.

Comment: Sorry about all the constant updates, trying to help you figure this out. i really think you need to redo the tables. Ensure all tables have a unique PK and think out what tables need a FK to a parent table. i outlined as best as i could for now. feel free to keep asking questions.

Comment: Perhaps the best structure would be 5 tables:

Pawnshop > Pawner > Loan > items, and 
Pawnshop > Pawner > Loan > payments.

That way you can write SQL to get you inventory and roll up your books.

Comment: @loxp In loan_assignment set the loan_id for 500 to 1 and 300 to 2. then on loan the value that is null for payment set the loan_id to 1 and the one with 200 set the loan_id to 2. should clear up your issue once you use distinct. Thank you it works like a charm..

Comment: glad that worked for you. Make sure each of your tables has a primary key and foreign key constraints, this will save you a lot of grief in the long run. Set your PK to auto incrementing integers if your getting confused when looking at the data seed them to different values like the first Pawner_ID can be 6000 and the first Item_ID can be 4000 just to help you visually. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it for you, althought, NOTE* i belive you are missing a column from your description of the table LOAN_Assignment (pawner_id)

```
SELECT a.date_loan_granted, p.pawner_id, p.name, c.item_name, l.principal_loan
FROM loan_assignment a
JOIN loan l ON l.loan_id = a.loan_id;
JOIN pawner p ON p.pawner_id = l.pawner_id
JOIN item c ON c.item_id = a.item_id
```

Comment: when I inserted this could an error occur which says unknown column 'pawner_id' in the field list

Comment: In your post i am starting to suspect you have the Loan and Loan Assignment tables mixed up when showing schema?

Comment: I am saying you keep referring to columns in LOAN_assignment that are in the load table according to your post right?